# A single word for the impact/effect of past events

Tags: single-word-requests

I am here to get a single word any that can describe the effect or impact of past events . . . for instance, if someone's wife was brutally killed and murdered, and his husband miss him a lot, he always thinks about the past events spent with her wife and weeps a lot for a long time over her murder. Then finally the husband of that woman get an effect on his mental as well as physical health due to the past events.

Meanwhile, a teacher of mine suggested me one hyphenated term that is [after-effect](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/after-effect), it means:

> an effect that follows after the primary action of something.

I think the term after-effect only suggest the primary actions of something, but doesn't clearly define about the past events. Is there any specific, single word that denotes the meaning which I want here?

Example with blank:

> the _____ of her murder led her husband to the severe mental disorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [afterburn](https://psychologenie.com/glossary-of-psychology-terms-definitions):

> In the field of Psychology, afterburn denotes a effect of past events, which influences the mental state and daily schedule of activities of an individual.

Also, the [Merriam Webster](https://psychologenie.com/glossary-of-psychology-terms-definitions) defines afterburn as follows:

> 2 : a period of lingering anger, fear, bitterness, etc., that follows a painful or traumatic event.

### Eric Berne, the father of transactional analysis, coined this word.

You can say like this:

> - The **afterburn** of her murder led her husband to the severe mental disorder.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the word "retrospective" would fit your context.

> (1) of, relating to, or given to retrospection (2) based on memory ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrospective))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the title question that does, however, need a different matrix sentence is **repercussion**.

> *repercussion* [noun]
>
> - (1) an effect or result, often indirect or remote, of some event or action

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/repercussion)]

> *repercussion* [noun]
>
> - the effect that an action, event, or decision has on something, especially a bad effect

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repercussion)]

*One of the repercussions of her murder was the ensuing severe mental disorder of her husband.*